# Data download from a REST API directly on AWS S3 bucket

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, api, rest, amazon-s3

I need to download data from a REST api by making a GET request from AWS cloud and land the data in S3. Do we have a REST connector available in AWS to make direct connection to API?

If not, then I plan to write Python code using **requests** library to make GET request to API using BASIC auth, write the response json into dataframe, flatten it and finally use **AWSwrangler **library to write the dataframe directly on to S3 bucket.

Is there any other simpler way to achieve it specially considering that the data may be over 5GB in size?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a presigned url first, then you can upload files directly to s3.

Everytime your api gets an upload request it will create a presigned url first then use that to upload data to s3.
[This](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/guide/s3-presigned-urls.html) might help.